# Meaning of cron expression 0 * * * * *

Tags: spring-boot, cron

I want to know about the meaning of this expression in

```
0 * * * * *
```

I think it means the scheduler is expected to run every seconds.Can anyone confirm me about this?

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
```

Comment: you can use https://crontab.guru to check your cron expressions

Comment: The crontab.guru is  not accurate. It only accepts five arguments.

Answer (score 5):

To be more precise , you can use `CronSequenceGenerator` to verify the execution time of a cron expression . Spring internally use this object to calculate the next triggered time of a cron expression.

For example, the following function will simply print out the next 10 triggered time.

```
public static void printNextTriggerTime(String cronExpression, LocalDateTime currentTime) {
        CronSequenceGenerator generator = new CronSequenceGenerator(cronExpression);
        Date d = Date.from(currentTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            d = generator.next(d);
            System.out.println(d);
        }
}
```

So , if I input :

```
printNextTriggerTime("0 * * * * *", LocalDateTime.of(2019, 8, 20, 15, 30, 0));
```

It will output :

```
Tue Aug 20 15:31:00 HKT 2019
Tue Aug 20 15:32:00 HKT 2019
Tue Aug 20 15:33:00 HKT 2019
Tue Aug 20 15:34:00 HKT 2019
Tue Aug 20 15:35:00 HKT 2019
Tue Aug 20 15:36:00 HKT 2019
Tue Aug 20 15:37:00 HKT 2019
Tue Aug 20 15:38:00 HKT 2019
Tue Aug 20 15:39:00 HKT 2019
Tue Aug 20 15:40:00 HKT 2019
```

which means `0 * * * * *` will run at every minute but not second.

Answer (score 0):

An update on the [answer by Ken Chan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57568611/239101) taking into account that `CronSequenceGenerator` is deprecated in Spring in favour of [CronExpression](https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions):

```java
    public static void printNextTime(String cronString) {
        CronExpression exp = CronExpression.parse(cronString);
        Stream.iterate(now(), exp::next).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

The call  `printNextTime("0 * * * * *");` generates:

```
2022-12-12T08:56:38.442809
2022-12-12T08:57
2022-12-12T08:58
2022-12-12T08:59
2022-12-12T09:00
2022-12-12T09:01
2022-12-12T09:02
2022-12-12T09:03
2022-12-12T09:04
2022-12-12T09:05
```